# Unity 3D Communication between 2 editors

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, tcp

I am trying to stream some data between 2 editors using a simple tcp client/server setup:

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Net; 
using System.Net.Sockets; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading; 
using UnityEngine;  

public class TCPTestServer : MonoBehaviour {    
    #region private members     
    /// <summary>   
    /// TCPListener to listen for incomming TCP connection  
    /// requests.   
    /// </summary>  
    private TcpListener tcpListener; 
    /// <summary> 
    /// Background thread for TcpServer workload.   
    /// </summary>  
    private Thread tcpListenerThread;   
    /// <summary>   
    /// Create handle to connected tcp client.  
    /// </summary>  
    private TcpClient connectedTcpClient;   
    #endregion  

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {         
        // Start TcpServer background thread        
        tcpListenerThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart(ListenForIncommingRequests));       
        tcpListenerThread.IsBackground = true;      
        tcpListenerThread.Start();  
    }   

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {        

            SendMessage();         

    }   

    /// <summary>   
    /// Runs in background TcpServerThread; Handles incomming TcpClient requests    
    /// </summary>  
    private void ListenForIncommingRequests () {        
        try {           
            // Create listener on localhost port 8052.          
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("myip"), 65535);          
            tcpListener.Start();              
            Debug.Log("Server is listening");              
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];              
            while (true) {              
                using (connectedTcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()) {                    
                    // Get a stream object for reading                  
                    using (NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream()) {                         
                        int length;                         
                        // Read incomming stream into byte arrary.                      
                        while ((length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0) {                           
                            var incommingData = new byte[length];                           
                            Array.Copy(bytes, 0, incommingData, 0, length);                             
                            // Convert byte array to string message.                            
                            string clientMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(incommingData);                             
                            Debug.Log("client message received as: " + clientMessage);                      
                        }                   
                    }               
                }           
            }       
        }       
        catch (SocketException socketException) {           
            Debug.Log("SocketException " + socketException.ToString());         
        }     
    }   
    /// <summary>   
    /// Send message to client using socket connection.     
    /// </summary>  
    private void SendMessage() {        
        if (connectedTcpClient == null) {             
            return;         
        }       

        try {           
            // Get a stream object for writing.             
            NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream();          
            if (stream.CanWrite) {                 
                string serverMessage = this.gameObject.transform.position.ToString();           
                // Convert string message to byte array.                 
                byte[] serverMessageAsByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverMessage);               
                // Write byte array to socketConnection stream.               
                stream.Write(serverMessageAsByteArray, 0, serverMessageAsByteArray.Length);               
                Debug.Log("Server sent his message - should be received by client");           
            }       
        }       
        catch (SocketException socketException) {             
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);         
        }   
    } 

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        tcpListenerThread.Abort();
        connectedTcpClient.Close ();

    }
}
```

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class TCPTestClient : MonoBehaviour {    
    #region private members     
    private TcpClient socketConnection;     
    private Thread clientReceiveThread;     
    #endregion      
    // Use this for initialization  
    void Start () {
        ConnectToTcpServer();     
    }   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {         
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {             
            SendMessage();         
        }     
    }   
    /// <summary>   
    /// Setup socket connection.    
    /// </summary>  
    private void ConnectToTcpServer () {        
        try {           
            clientReceiveThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart(ListenForData));          
            clientReceiveThread.IsBackground = true;            
            clientReceiveThread.Start();        
        }       
        catch (Exception e) {           
            Debug.Log("On client connect exception " + e);      
        }   
    }   
    /// <summary>   
    /// Runs in background clientReceiveThread; Listens for incomming data.     
    /// </summary>     
    private void ListenForData() {      
        try {           
            socketConnection = new TcpClient("myip", 65535);            
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];             
            while (true) {              
                // Get a stream object for reading              
                using (NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream()) {                   
                    int length;                     
                    // Read incomming stream into byte arrary.                  
                    while ((length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0) {                       
                        var incommingData = new byte[length];                       
                        Array.Copy(bytes, 0, incommingData, 0, length);                         
                        // Convert byte array to string message.                        
                        string serverMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(incommingData);                         
                        Debug.Log("server message received as: " + serverMessage);                  
                    }               
                }           
            }         
        }         
        catch (SocketException socketException) {             
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);         
        }     
    }   
    /// <summary>   
    /// Send message to server using socket connection.     
    /// </summary>  
    private void SendMessage() {         
        if (socketConnection == null) {             
            return;         
        }       
        try {           
            // Get a stream object for writing.             
            NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream();            
            if (stream.CanWrite) {                 
                string clientMessage = "This is a message from one of your clients.";               
                // Convert string message to byte array.                 
                byte[] clientMessageAsByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clientMessage);               
                // Write byte array to socketConnection stream.                 
                stream.Write(clientMessageAsByteArray, 0, clientMessageAsByteArray.Length);                 
                //Debug.Log("Client sent his message - should be received by server");             
            }         
        }       
        catch (SocketException socketException) {             
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);         
        }     
    } 

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        clientReceiveThread.Abort();
        socketConnection.Close ();

    }
}
```

This works in local but wont work if i run the server and client seperately in two different computers. Moreover, i triend ping.eu and my port seems closed even if i forwarded from my firewall settings. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say locally, do you mean locally on the same computer or locally on the same LAN?

Comment: Also, are you sure you are port forwarding on the router, or are you opening that port on your "server" machines firewall?

Comment: I am in a  workplace and have 1 laptop and 1 pc with different connections. I even tried the same thing where the laptop was connected through 3g using an android phone

Comment: So locally, same machine or same network?  Telling me how your testing it without telling me what you consider local doesn't help(also I have no idea if those tests failed?).  To me locally is within the same network without going on to the internet.

Comment: The reason this is important to know is because it will help me to understand if could be a setting with your code, a setting with your computer, or a setting with the router/network.

Comment: I tested on the same network when i use 1 laptop and 1 pc via Lan (different ips however is a workplace) and also i tested in when 1 laptop is connected via 3G.

Comment: So the LAN test was successfully connected?

Comment: Not between two different pcs, only when executed un the same unity editor

Comment: Lan only worked if i use those 2 scripts in the same pc running 1 unity editor not between 2 pcs

Comment: 1.You have to show the actual IP you used for the server and client. You omitted those parts out in the code in question. 2. Also, you are not answering Eddge's question. Does it work if you test it on different PC's connected to **the-same lan**?

Comment: Without a clear clarification on how your setup is working I am left to assume it is something with your network setup, and only because you state "Moreover, i tried ping.eu and my port seems closed even if i forwarded from my firewall settings",  This tells me by itself either you didn't open the port correctly in your firewall settings on your machine with the server, or you didn't setup the port correctly on your network(Usually through your routers/modems admin panel)

Comment: I will try to do this from my house where i have access to the router thanks!